# pacman::p_load() cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/PACKAGES'

Tags: r, package, repository, load, pacman

I have been using the pacman package to automatically install and load packages and libraries at the start of my scripts, e.g.:

```
pacman::p_load(ggplot2, dplyr)
```

Since recently, I get the following error message:

```
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/4.3:
cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/PACKAGES'
```

Checking the URL to the given package repository (https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/), I see that packages are only provided unit R version 3.4. See screen shot below:

[image]

So I wonder if this is a temporary problem, pacman is not being continued or if I need/can change the URL manually to look for packages elsewhere (for e.g. https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/)?

Would there be any convenient alternative to pacman::p_load() if there is no option to have it working again?

Comment: Did you at one point manually change your CRAN repo? What does `getOption("repos")` return for you? Maybe try running `pacman ::p_set_cranrepo()` to set a repo. The default should be "http://cran.rstudio.com/". The `pacman` package should still be working fine; you just seem to have some non-standard configuration at the moment.